# .htaccess rewriterule - substitution from rewritecond the_request

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, request, substitution

I have a message board where occasionally a request comes in with characters encoded, and if a redirect isn't set up, the visitor would get back a 404 response.

E.g., the request for topic #309 comes in as viewtopic.php%3Ft%3D309 rather than viewtopic.php?t=309

And so I have a redirect set up as follows:

```
# Redirect from calls to incorrect topic constructs to the actual topic link
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} viewtopic\.php%3Ft%3D([0-9]+)
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/viewtopic.php?t=%1 [R=301,L]
```

I look at %{THE_REQUEST} as it's the only way to see a request with encoding. Then I select as a substitution, one or more digits after %3D (the = sign).

What's happening is that, according to my logs, the rewrite condition is being matched, and the rewriterule is fired, but it redirects to

```
http://www.example.com/viewtopic.php?t=
```

That is, the substitution doesn't fill in the topic number.

Before this issue, I hadn't had any problem with substituting from a rewritecond (via %1, %2, etc.) before.  Is there something particular about substituting from %{THE_REQUEST} or am I missing something?

Running Apache 2.2.22 on Linux.

Comment: Try to avoid using `THE_REQUEST`... debug what is in `REQUEST_URI` in such a situation and do rewrite based on `REQUEST_URI` and/or `QUERY_STRING`. Btw. it's very strange, as at least one digit have to be in `%1` after the match. Are you sure the URLs has been rewritten by rules you quoted in your question?

Comment: The problem with doing that is that these other variables decode the request or query string.  And if it's decoded, I don't have a way of dealing with it -- because if it's decoded, it looks like a normal request.

Comment: The answer to "Are you sure...?" is yes.  There's no other possible rewrite that could have done it.  This is a very specific rewrite.

Comment: I'm aware of the content of `THE_REQUEST` - I mean, it has to be decoded into variables and they have to have some content - even badly encoded. Then you can catch it... Btw. on my system when I put `GET /viewtopic.php%3Ft%3D12 HTTP/1.0` as request, `mod_rewrite` works in normal way... decoding is correct.

Comment: In this case, I'm not wanting to match a decoded version of the request, as the decoded version looks normal.  If I checked the decoded version, it wouldn't rewrite, and then the user would get a 404 response.

Answer (score 0):

The matched expression should be in brackets `(.*)` and then it should show up in `$1`.

BTW, do you really want a redirect as this would go back to the device which might escape it again before redirecting.  You might want to do a passthrough `[PT]` or something else.

Comment: Do you mean the .* within rewriterule?

Comment: Also, I haven't seen a case (yet) where the device is re-escaping.

Comment: `RewriteRule /viewtopic\.php\%3Ft\%3D(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/viewtopic.php?t=$1 [R=301,L]` (not tested)

Comment: AFAIK, you can't match encoded characters that way.  Also, I'm wanting to match a number, not any characters.

Comment: To be more specific, by the time RewriteRule is looking at it, the %3F and %3D will have been decoded to ? and =, thus the rule won't be executed.

Comment: Aha. Then the initial matching regular expression in the first part of the rule should be changed to just match the digit sequence.